# SQL Server 2008+: Modulo and Decimal / Numeric data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, modulo

My question is:

Is it a valid operation to use the modulo operator `%` in combination with `decimal` or `numeric` data types in T-SQL.

It seems to work as far as I've tested it, but is this actually an intended behaviour for `decimal` values like `SELECT 2.0 % 0.4` to result `0.0` and can I rely on that?

My idea was to create a query like this:

```
SELECT itemNumber
    FROM item i
    JOIN orderItem oi ON i.ID = oi.itemID
    WHERE oi.orderID = @orderID
    AND oi.amount % i.amount <> 0.0000
```

I was actually surprised that it seems to work. Is this intended behaviour?

I was expecting that only to work for integer values and was prepared to use something different.

For the background:

We're selling some of our stuff measured in meters in a prepackaged form. The data field in the database is a `numeric(18,4)` value and some prepackaged units are packaged to decimal values. Now I have to create a procedure to check if that item sold is a multiple of a prepackaged unit or not, do determine if we can send a valid amount of prepackaged items of if it is necessary to cut the item appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous to use `%` operator for decimal numbers, because internal representation of decimal number can differ from expecting. For example, you can get `0.40000000000000001` instead of `0.4`
And query `SELECT 2.0 % 0.40000000000000001` will return `0.39999999999999996`.
Maybe, you should use [`CEILING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) function to get number of whole items:

```
SELECT CEILING(2.0 / 0.40000000000000001) --5
```

Comment: With a numeric(18,4) the precision should be high enough I think?

Comment: @Adwaenyth it depends on your environment, if you measure `amount` in tonns - you should add more digits to the right side, if you use gramms, i think, it's enough

Comment: It's meters actually.

Comment: @Adwaenyth, well, 4 is enough